# Access is denied when try to read a local xml file using ajax request on IE only

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I am trying to read a local file `forms.xml` from an single html page (not an application ).
Javascript code :

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","forms.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
}
```

I think my code is correct because it doing good in `firefox` and `crome` but in IE its saying

```
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
```

on line `xmlhttp.open("GET","forms.xml",false);`

Now i have read some post concerning this issue they all give different solution and some say its a problem in IE 9 but i am using **`10.0.9200`**

Possible explanation and solution please.

Comment: Is this running on Windows 8 by any chance?

Comment: no the os is Windows 7 Professional (SP1) 64 bit.

Comment: Are you running locally or using a webserver?

Comment: locally and not even in a local server its just a single html file opened in browser.

Comment: In IE AJAX works with http(s) protocol only.

Comment: is there a way to send https ajax request.? if yes please give a hint. @Teemu

Comment: You've to host the page on a server or IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code is working on any older browser starting from IE5

```
try{
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }catch(e){
    try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
    }
    catch(e){
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e)    {
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e)    {
                alert("XMLHTTP Not Supported On Your Browser");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with cross domain requests. XMLHttprequest needs to be called on the same domain only and running via a http request. Running your page locally with no server will cause the access denied error in IE (as well as most other browsers)

If you are just testing you can try overriding a setting in IE to see if it helps.

You can enable cross-domain on IE by going into Internet Options -> Security Settings ->Custom level and enabling "Access data sources across domains".

Comment: lowering the security not helping by the way as you said `most browser` i tried with `firefox` and `crome` not even a warning. although its not conventional to do this way, i am doing a RnD. And thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

use `xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")`

Comment: IE 10 will be using the native object branch of the if/else so this line of code would never be hit.

Comment: @Quentin: I meant to use my code only without any if/else. As I know this can only be executed when (if) part will be removed :) Please do not discourage newcomers....I am here for learning.

Comment: Then it won't work in non-IE browsers (or IE 11 IIRC), and that's assuming that using the ActiveX implementation fixes the problem anyway.